# Logging in on the Grails web interface is not longer working

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm working on a web interface in Grails and use spring-security-core and a PostgreSQL database.
I have several databases that I need to link to the user database as well.
Now I can no longer login and as an error in the web interface it shows that the combination of username and password can not be found.
I find this strange because when I login into the database via the command line, I can see that the user has been created.

The complete code can be found on github with the following link https://github.com/rm93/BIGC.

Comment: Not sure of your exact problem (definitely using the correct database?) but did notice you have underscores in the names of some of your domain classes and fields. In my experience it's best to avoid this with Grails & stick to camel case.

Comment: I see what you mean but I think that is not the problem. I have tested that and it works fine. My problem is that I can't login to my project. When I use the correct username and password I get the prompt which says that it can't find the username and password combination.